# How to resolve "Url reservation add failed, Error: 87"?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm following the following thread to configure SSRS for SSL.

[Configure SSRS for SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372139/configure-ssrs-for-ssl)

Here's what I have.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://dbserver.mydomain.org:443/Reportserver_Test/ user="NT Service\ReportServer$Test" listen=yes addl=S-1-5-80-3637326371-3941449338-1192580090-1447153118-1238582853
```

And the error is:

Url reservation add failed, Error: 87
The parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with the command I've used; however, here's how I resolved the issue with SSL in SSRS.

1. I opened up the rereportserver.config file
2. Delete everything in the  tags
3. Restart SQL Server Reporting Services
4. Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager
5. Re-setup Web Services URl with SSL Certificate
6. Click Apply

This seems to work for me for the moment.